# Problems with OnMouseDown() event Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I am doing some tutorials, but one drove me crazy. I have a rotating cube with a box collider on it. All events work except OnMouseDown(). I don't know what is the problem... Here is a snippet of code.

```
void onMouseDown() {        
    Debug.Log ("On Mouse Down Event!!!!!!!!!");
}

void OnMouseUp() {
    Debug.Log("On Mouse Up Event");
}

void OnMouseOver() {
    Debug.Log("On Mouse Over Event");
}

void OnMouseEnter() {
    Debug.Log("On Mouse Enter Event");
}

void OnMouseDrag() {
    Debug.Log("On Mouse Drag Event");
}
```

In the console, the message "On Mouse Down Event!!!!!!!!!" doesn't appear not matter my great number of clicks on the cube.

Comment: you forgot to capitalise the `o` in `OnMouseDown` even the wiki highlighting picks it up :P

Comment: For more related info: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/716227/onmouse-event-handlers-might-impact-performance-mo.html

Answer (score 16):

```
void OnMouseDown() 
{        
    Debug.Log("On Mouse Down Event!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Your `OnMouseDown` method needs to be written with a capital `O`, not a lower case one. Try that and it should work.

Comment: No compiler complains, because the method name is legal.

Comment: Also (just in case you're planning on making anything for android/iphone), these mouse methods only work on computers (linux, window, iOS, flash, web etc). If you're making a game for mobiles, you'll need to look into other methods (Input.MouseDown or Input.Touch with raycasting to get touched objects for example)

Comment: @StevenMills actually, it's not necessary — this methods are automatically used on touch devices too, where applicable. I built a desktop game for mobile recently, just to test it, and all interface and interactions worked, although without support for events like OnMouseOver, obviously.